# why '&' changes the behaviour of the object?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm studying C++ form Thinking in C++ V1. I came across an example that demonstrates inheritance. Here it goes

```
#include <iostream>

class Instrument{
public:
    virtual void play(){
        std::cout<<"instrument::play()";
    }
};

class Wind: public Instrument{
public:
    void play(){
        std::cout<<"Wind::play()";
    }
};

void tune(Instrument& i){
    i.play();
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Wind flute;
    tune(flute);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs `Wind::play()` on the console.

But if I change the method 'tune' to

```
void tune(Instrument i){
    i.play();
}
```

The output will `instrument::play()`

Since the '&' is added so that the reference of flute is passed instead of a copy, why does the program output `instrument::play()` instead of `Wind::play()` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/274634/2101267

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The polymorphic behavior of an object expression in C++ is determined by its *dynamic type*.

- When you *attach a reference* of type `Instrument &i` to an object of type `Wind`, the dynamic type of the object referred by `i` is *preserved*. I.e. even though `i` is declared with type `Instrument`, it actually *refers to* an actual object of type `Wind`. And that is why `i` continues to behave as `Wind`. The same would be true if you *refer to* some object with a *pointer*.

  Speaking in formal language, it means that *static type* of expression `i` is `Instrument`, but *dynamic type* if the same expression is `Wind`. For this reason, `i` behaves polymorphically as `Wind`.
- Meanwhile, when you *assign* (or *initialize*) an object `Instrument i` with a value of type `Wind`, you create an independent standalone object `i` of type `Instrument`. The type of this object is `Instrument`. So that standalone copy `i` will behave as `Instrument` in all polymorphic contexts.

  Again, speaking in formal language, it means that in this case both *static type* and *dynamic type* of expression `i` is `Instrument`. For this reason, `i` behaves polymorphically as `Instrument`.

In C++ language the only way to "preserve" a dynamic type of the object is to *refer to* that object with pointers or references. "Refer" is the key word here: you do not create new objects, but rather  *refer to* already existing objects. And those existing objects continue to behave in accordance with their native type. An object of type `Wind` continues to behave as an object of type `Wind`. (Note that this applies to *polymorphic* behavior only, e.g. to how *virtual* function calls are resolved.)

But whenever you create an independent *copy* of an object (instead of *referring* to the original), that copy acquires a life of its own, with its own type and related properties. A standalone copy of type `Instrument` has no relation to the original `Wind` object. It has no memory of the fact that it was born as a copy of a `Wind` object. It behaves as an `Instrument`.

Answer (score 17):

Because the **copy** that gets passed has type `Instrument`, not type `Wind`, because `Instrument` is the type that the function takes. This is known as "slicing".

Comment: This is really the most correct answer- an `Instrument` can only ever be an `Instrument`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem called "[slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)". When you copy `Wind` into an `Instrument` it becomes an `Instrument`.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
void tune(Instrument i){
    i.play();
}
```

You create a new instance if the `Instrument` object, and the `Instrument` object will print `instrument::play`

When you used the reference operator `&` you referred to an existing object that was of the `Wind` type.

Answer (score -2):

The reason that the `Instrument::play` function is called, is because when you pass a copy, it's actually the `Instrument` part of the object you pass, since you [*slice*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) the object.

Comment: This is technically correct, but utterly unhelpful and doesn't actually explain the OP's confusion.

Comment: @DeadMG I was to quick to answer, was still writing on it. And removed the other (unneeded) info too.